# Hive sql extract one to multiple values from key value pairs

Tags: sql, hive

I have a column that looks like:

```
[{"key_1":true,"key_2":true,"key_3":false},{"key_1":false,"key_2":false,"key_3":false},...]
```

There can be 1 to many items described by parameters in {} in the column.

I would like to extract values only of parameters described by key_1. Is there a function for that? I tried so far json related functions (json_tuple, get_json_object) but each time I received null.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below json path.

```sql
WITH sample_data AS (
 SELECT '[{"key_1":true,"key_2":true,"key_3":false},{"key_1":false,"key_2":false,"key_3":false}]' json
)
SELECT get_json_object(json, '$[*].key_1') AS key1_values FROM sample_data;
```

**Query results**

[image]